# How to combine two different datasets to create a unified dataset

Tags: dataset, code-request

I have two different datasets : `dsDat1` and `dsDat2`:

```
ClearAll[dat1, dat2, col1, col2, row1, row2, dsDat1, dsDat2];
SeedRandom[123];
dat1 = RandomInteger[5, {10, 5}];
col1 = {"BOS", "labor", "revenue", "worker", "share"};
row1 = {"agr", "min", "ma1", "ma3", "ma5", "soth", "sbus", "stel", 
   "segw", "sfin"};
dsDat1 = 
 Dataset@AssociationThread[row1, AssociationThread[col1, #] & /@ dat1]

dat2 = RandomInteger[5, {10, 5}];
col2 = {"Numb1", "Tot", "Rev", "Per", "Share"};
row2 = {"min", "agr", "ma5", "ma3", "ma1", "stel", "soth", "sbus", 
   "segw", "sdummy"};
dsDat2 = 
 Dataset@AssociationThread[row2, AssociationThread[col2, #] & /@ dat2]
```

I want to create a single `unified` dataset by combining the two different datasets using the row keys in `dsDat1` as a reference. There are some complications though. The second dataset `dsDat2` is not perfectly matching
`dsDat1` in terms of row keys.

Here are the places they do not match:

1. The order of the row keys in `dsDat2` is mixed compared to those in `dsDat1`;
2. Some row keys in `dsDat2` do not exist in `dsDat1`, and some row keys in `dsDat1` do not exist in `dsDat2`;

I like to handle those cases in items 1 and 2 as follows:

1. Consider the row keys in `dsDat1` as fixed,
   and create a new row at the end of the `unified` dataset for each row key that does not exist in `dsDat1` but in `dsDat2`;
2. For the missing row keys in `dsDat2` (compared to `dsDat1`), place `MissingValue[]`  in the unified dataset;

Basically, I just want to create a unified dataset by combining two different datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better way:

```
KeyUp[ds_] := KeyValueMap[<|"key" -> #1, #2|> &, Normal @ ds]

up = KeyUp /@ {dsDat1, dsDat2};

join = JoinAcross[Sequence @@ up, "key", "Outer"];

KeySort /@ GroupBy[join, First -> Rest, Last] // Dataset
```

[image]

We can put this in one function:

```
Consolidate[a_, b_] :=
 Dataset @ Map[KeySort] @
   GroupBy[
    JoinAcross[Sequence @@ Map[KeyUp, {a, b}], "key", "Outer"],
    First -> Rest,
    Last]

Consolidate[dsDat1, dsDat2]
```

(* output like above *)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. The updated version is much more compact and works for me. There is one tiny issue you might want to consider to revise the code. The keys of the first dataset should be used as reference and hence be placed at the top in the final dataset and the keys of the 2nd dataset at the bottom. This means that the key `sdummy` in the final dataset should follow the key `sfin`.

Comment: Thank you very much for acceptance. The tiny problem can be easily solved by swapping the arguments: `Consolidate[dsDat2, dsDat1]`

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time...

Comment: It's always a pleasure working with you :)

Answer (score 3):

It's cumbersome:

```
a = Normal @ dsDat1 // KeySort;

b = Normal @ dsDat2 // KeySort;

ab = First @ Complement[Keys @ a, Keys @ b]
```

"sfin"

```
ba = First @ Complement[Keys @ b, Keys @ a]
```

"sdummy"

```
k = Intersection[Keys @ a, Keys @ b];

aa = Values @ KeyTake[k] @ a;

bb = Values @ KeyTake[k] @ b;

Join[
  KeySort /@ AssociationThread[k -> Table[Join[aa[[i]], bb[[i]]], {i, Length @ aa}]],
  <|"sfin" -> KeySort @ Association @ KeyUnion[{a[ab], b[ba]}]|>,
  <|"sdummy" -> KeySort @ Association @ KeyUnion[{b[ba], a[ab]}]|>] // Dataset
```

[image]